# terminal history clearing automatically

Tags: linux, bash

My bash shell is clearing its history automatically and I am unable to figure out whats wrong.

I have looked at the bashrc file and these are the settings

```
HISTSIZE=5000
HISTFILESIZE=10000
```

Can some one suggest what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: When is bash shell clearing its history automatically? On logout?

Answer (score 1):

It's can be rewrited by different sessions
Try to add it:

```
  shopt -s histappend
  PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `~/.bash_history` may not be writable

Comment: It has permissions set to read and write. I dont think thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's can be this line in bash init files:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

Or this variable is undefined.

Or in file `bash_logout` maybe remove the history-file.

See also: http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/Shell-game-Managing-Bash-command-history